# Webform submissions to be seen on Drupalgap

Tags: webforms, javascript

I am making a DrupalGap application to view Webform submission.

I have made a view in Drupal as a table to list the submissions, now I want to see that table in DrupalGap.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [DrupalGap Views Render Array](http://drupalgap.org/node/219). With it you will:

1. Create the Views JSON page display in Views with contextual filter(s)
2. Create a page in the app to display the view
3. Use the Views Render Array to send up the contextual filter(s)
4. Build the render function to render each row of the table

Comment: (http://imgur.com/NrbwksF) Its counting my submissions but the text itsn't shown or the titles...

Comment: You need to adjust the `row_callback` function to put your desired content. Preview the JSON in Views to understand how to extract and render the data in your custom DG module.

Answer (score 0):

The [Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) module can help with that:

> Views support for the Services module version 3.x and later.
>
> It has currently two features:
>
> - Create view based resource creating Services display in a view
> - Execute any view of the system via views resource call

The second feature will allow you to query a resource for a particular View's data, with arguments, and you can code your Drupalgap application to do whatever you like with it.